# What's the relation between malloc diagnostics and malloc related environment variables?

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode4, memory-management, malloc

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-MallocOptions/_index.html) there's a list of environment variables about the malloc package:

- MallocStackLogging
- MallocStackLoggingNoCompact
- MallocPreScribble
- MallocScribble
- MallocGuardEdges
- MallocDoNotProtectPrelude
- MallocDoNotProtectPostlude
- MallocCheckHeapStart
- MallocCheckHeapEach
- MallocCheckHeapSleep
- MallocCheckHeapAbort
- MallocBadFreeAbort

Also, when I open the Diagnostics section of my project from XCode 4, I see that under Memory Management, there are

- Enable Scribble
- Enable Guard Edges
- Enable Guard Malloc

So, I'm a little bit confused. Should these environment variables be used in combination with the diagnostics settings, or are these diagnostics settings a shortcut for enabling the environment variables listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge they're shortcuts to the most common options; to use the others you need to set with environment variables.